# fabric.js loop objects based on position from top left

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Hi I have a canvas with multiple images placed and i want to loop through the images from top left postion and and all the way down.

```
  Lets say i have 10 images placed on canvas 
    [1] [2] [3] [4] [5]
    [6] [7] [8] [9] [10]

  I have changed position of some of the images 
    [9] [5] [3] [4] [2]
    [6] [7] [8] [10] [1]
  i want to loop in the similar order based on position from top left
```

Sorry i could not create/show a example

Right now the foreach in fabric.js considers based on object added and based on z-index if i may be correct .

Is there any way i can loop through objects based on position from top left.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straight-forward seeming technique would involve heavy use of the `fabric.Object` class's `intersectsWithRect` method. It takes two points as the parameters which make up a square.

Use this method on all of the objects on the canvas, and you can see which ones intersect with this square.

My advice is to split your entire canvas into a grid of these squares, and loop through each square, starting at the top left square and working down to the bottom right one. You will certainly need to use something like two for loops to test every square.

When testing every square, if you see that one of the objects on the canvas *do* intersect with that square, add it to the resulting array.

Eventually, when you get to the end of grid, your array will be complete!

The issue you may have is how big each square can be. The smaller the square is, the more accurate your list will be, yet the slower the process will be for it all to complete.

The larger the square, the less accurate it may be, yet the loops will complete much quicker.

I mention accuracy only because you have the ability to stack objects on a canvas, and this technique will just tell you if an object intersects with the area created by the two points or not. It does not tell you which order they are in inside of the 'cell' of the canvas grid.

Hope this helped!